# How to move a folder to another folder PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to move a folder name $Part to products folder.
I tried this way, but it is not working.

```
$folder = "../pending_newProducts/$Part";
$destination = "../products/" ;     
rename($folder,$destination);
```

Comment: Is there a way to move a entire folder instead of file by file.

Comment: The second argument to `rename` needs the destination name, not just the folder. `../products/$Part`. It's not like the `mv` command, which understands moving *into* a directory.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I have solved my problem by using @Barmar solution.